# How to get current command register value/name in Vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

Currently I have this mapping:

```
  nmap <silent> x :set opfunc=SpecialChange<CR>g@
  function! SpecialChange(type)
    silent exec 'normal! `[v`]"_dP'
  endfunction
```

it helps me to substitute some value with the default register value.

However, I want to be able to replace the value with some specific register,
for this I need to know the current command register value or name (or better both).
For example, when I press `"axiw"` I want to substitute the word with `a` register,
but I need to understand that `a` register was pressed not `b` or `c` or something else.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `:h v:register`

Comment: I've tried to add this line `echom 'pressed ' .. v:register` into my function, however, it returns `pressed +`. So I got `+` instead of the name of the register that was used.

Comment: If you got "+" then, well, it's "+". Maybe you have `set clipboard=unnamedplus`, for example.

Comment: nope, I was trying to write this in a totally new vim configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking inspiration from the example provided under `:help :map-operator`, this is how your function should look:

```
nnoremap <expr> <key> SpecialChange()
function! SpecialChange(type = '')
    if a:type == ''
        set opfunc=SpecialChange
        return 'g@'
    endif
    execute 'normal! `[v`]"_d"' .. v:register .. 'P'
endfunction
```

Explanation:

- We use an `<expr>` mapping because of this quote:

  > An `<expr>` mapping is used to be able to fetch any prefixed count and register.
- `SpecialChange()` takes a single `type` argument, with an empty string as default value.
- When called without arguments, the function sets `opfunc` to itself and finally returns `g@`. This is another way of doing:

  ```
  :set opfunc=SpecialChange<CR>g@
  ```
- When called as an `operatorfunc`, `SpecialChange()` gets a `type` argument with a value of `line`, `char`, or `block`, so we skip the conditional and go directly to the meat of the function, where we can use `v:register` because we are in an `<expr>` mapping:

  ```
  execute 'normal! `[v`]"_d"' .. v:register .. 'P'
  ```

It's all kind of contrived but that's what we have to work with.

Comment: I like your approach more, you have a single function and no global variables, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was losing the current register name. Here is the solution that works for me:

```
nmap x :call SetActiveRegister()<CR>:set opfunc=SpecialChange<CR>g@

let g:activeRegisterName = ''

function! SpecialChange(type)
  silent exec 'normal! `[v`]"_di' .. getreg(g:activeRegisterName)
endfunction

function! SetActiveRegister()
  let g:activeRegisterName = v:register
endfunction
```